# Force boost logging core to shutdown?

Tags: boost-log

Is there a way to force destruction of the boost logging core singleton? It can accessed via:

```
boost::log::core::get();
```

Which returns a shared pointer to the logging core. However, I need to shutdown / de-allocate it explicitly before my application closes other resources / detaches dll etc...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the singleton only gets destroyed on application termination. But depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can make it release certain resources. For instance, by calling `remove_all_sinks` you can make it release all sinks, which will cause their destruction, unless they are referenced to from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, for chiming in Andrey.

It seems remove_all_sinks is not helping.

I am using the log in a plugin and when my plugin is unloaded, it seems the boost log dll is getting detached and then something in the boost thread lib is trying to access the memory of boost log. I am explicitly calling flush and removing all sinks on plugin unload but it does not seem to help.

Only boost log is using the boost threading lib.

Comment: 1. Boost.Log does not support plugin unloading because it saves references to various static data and code internally. When the library is unloaded, those references become dangling. Note that flushing or removing sinks will not fix this completely. 2. Boost.Log only creates threads of its own when async logging is used, and those threads are joined when their sinks are destroyed. So there should be no Boost.Log's threads active after `remove_all_sinks` returns. If they are still active, please create a ticket with a repro and a backtrace.

Comment: Thanks, @andrey-semashev. This info is very useful.