# Why crash inside boost log when program terminate

Tags: c++, boost

I have my application using boost logger. When I terminate my program using killall `myApplication`. There is core file generated. I then use `gdb` and see the trace. I also tried some related fix but not useful. [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/why_crash_on_term.html)

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ff95f9aa801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ff96240f84a in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
    at /home/nwani/m3/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1560109574129/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x00007ff96240df47 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>)
    at /home/nwani/m3/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1560109574129/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
#4  0x00007ff96240d3a5 in __cxa_call_terminate (ue_header=ue_header@entry=0x55c83e48bfd0)
    at /home/nwani/m3/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1560109574129/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_call.cc:54
#5  0x00007ff96240dbd8 in __cxxabiv1::__gxx_personality_v0 (version=<optimized out>, actions=6, exception_class=5138137972254386944, ue_header=0x55c83e48bfd0, context=0x7ffc786aaa90)
    at /home/nwani/m3/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1560109574129/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_personality.cc:677
#6  0x00007ff96235aaab in _Unwind_RaiseException_Phase2 (exc=exc@entry=0x55c83e48bfd0, context=context@entry=0x7ffc786aaa90, frames_p=frames_p@entry=0x7ffc786aa998)
    at /home/nwani/m3/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1560109574129/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/unwind.inc:64
#7  0x00007ff96235af49 in _Unwind_Resume (exc=0x55c83e48bfd0) at /home/nwani/m3/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1560109574129/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/libgcc/unwind.inc:241
#8  0x000055c83c2e5be1 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex::unlock_shared (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/log/detail/light_rw_mutex.hpp:115
#9  boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>::unlock_shared (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/log/sources/threading_models.hpp:78
#10 boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::shared_lock_guard<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::~shared_lock_guard (this=<optimized out>,
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/log/detail/locks.hpp:146
#11 boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<severity_level>, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::severity<severity_level> > >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, severity_level const> > (this=this@entry=0x55c83e46b798, args=...) at /usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:458
```

My application is running on linux. In class destructor, I have log printing. The core file shows that that is the crashing point. I would like to ask if that is some config problem or a wrong usage of the boost library?

Comment: You probably need to tell the boost log to stop logging prior to shutdown. This could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368720/force-boost-logging-core-to-shutdown

Comment: You're having an uncaught exception. Try catching and inspecting it to find out where and why it is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and update this thread if I have progress

Comment: I printed the exception and I get `Failed to set TLS value: Invalid argument`, I guess that is related to ` _Unwind_RaiseException_Phase2` ? But I am not sure why and how to fix it.

Comment: @SvenNilsson, thanks, I have tried that. But the problem still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that at the point when your class destructor is called the thread-local storage used for the severity level is already destroyed. Because of this, initiating a log record fails with an exception, and since you don't catch it, the program aborts.

It is [recommended](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/init_term_support.html) to avoid logging during program termination. However, if you really do need that instance of logging, you may try changing the logger type to [`logger_mt`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.basic_logger). This will remove the severity level from the log records emitted through that logger, but you could emulate it with [scoped logger attributes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.related_components.scoped_attributes).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.